# Open Layers GeoTIFF

Tags: openlayers

Hi can somebody explain how to work with ol.GeoTIFF layer? I tried this tutorial https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/cog/true-color.html

OL version : 6.14.1
I tried to load the layer like this:

```
const geoTiffLayer = new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
        id: `geoTiffs`,
        zIndex: 3,
        source: new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
            sources: [
                {
                    url: 'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/21/H/UB/2021/9/S2B_21HUB_20210915_0_L2A/TCI.tif'
                }
            ]
        })
    });

    olMap.addLayer(geoTiffLayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you are using the latest `ol.js` and your `olMap` is set up correctly:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/main/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-container" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      const projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:32721',
        units: 'm',
      });
      const sourceExtent = [300000, 6090260, 409760, 6200020];
      const olMap = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map-container',
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: projection,
          center: ol.extent.getCenter(sourceExtent),
          extent: sourceExtent,
          zoom: 1,
        })
      });

      const geoTiffLayer = new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
        id: `geoTiffs`,
        zIndex: 3,
        source: new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
          sources: [
            {
              url: 'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/21/H/UB/2021/9/S2B_21HUB_20210915_0_L2A/TCI.tif'
            },
          ],
        }),
      });

      olMap.addLayer(geoTiffLayer);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```